# About executor declaration

Tags: java, interface

In the [Executor Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) section of the Java™ tutorials:

> The `java.util.concurrent` package defines three executor interfaces:
>
> - `Executor`, a simple interface that supports launching new tasks.
> - `ExecutorService`, a subinterface of `Executor`, which adds features that help manage the lifecycle, both of the individual tasks and of the executor itself.
> - `ScheduledExecutorService`, a subinterface of `ExecutorService`, supports future and/or periodic execution of tasks.
>
> Typically, variables that refer to executor objects are declared as one of these three interface types, not with an executor class type.

What does the last sentence mean?  Does it mean something like this:

```
Executor e = new AClassImplementsTheExecutorInterface();
```

If so, why?

Comment: It is a good idea and considered a best practice to program against an interface so you are not tied to a particular implementation. This way the particular implementation can be more easily changed even at runtime. Executors are often created using the `Executors` utility methods.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would declare an executor from the `java.util.concurrent`:

```
ScheduledExecutorService myExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

This is a scheduled executor service which extends `ExecutorService` and is ready to go. However if you want to create your own executor class it would something like this

```
public class MyExecutor implements Executor {

    public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

depending on which executor you choose it will be more or less specialized. The broader `Executor` will only make you implement the execute method but others will have more since they are more specialized.

Answer (score 0):

That means you are not dealing with concrete implementation directly. Instead you are accessing concrete class through interface:

`Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();` returns instance of `DelegatedScheduledExecutorService` that implements `ScheduledExecutorService`. It wouldn't be a good practice to depend on concretions instead of abstractions. `java.util.concurrent` package is one of many interface based programming examples.